# Multdimensionnal input for LSTM for Tensor Flow

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I have a series of multdimensionnal time series as follow:

```
Input Xi   i=1..N samples
```

`Xi=[y1,..yk..., yT]          K=1..T  , yk is a vector,  T= 50 (sequence length)
   with  yk= [yk1, ... ykm]   m=3`
      with ykj : Float

Using LSTM Tensor Flow,would like to predict the next step (T+1), given the training of samples like :

```
Xi=[y1,...., yT]`
```

The current code gives input form for m=1 (unidimensionnal Y),

```
input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batchSize, numSteps, numInputs])
targets = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batchSize, numSteps, numInputs])
```

Wondering if there is a way to input data if m=2, 3 in the LSTM tensor flow ?

If not, is there a workaround to input multdimensionnal time series ?

References are here (this does not reply to the question of multi dimension):

- [LSTM inputs for Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875652/lstm-inputs-for-tensorflow)
- [Understanding Tensorflow LSTM models input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428157/understanding-tensorflow-lstm-models-input)

Comment: Did you check the documentation of tensorflow ? https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/recurrent/index.html